# Why do I need a custom domain in order to have SSL to my endpoint

Tags: security, azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

This is more a theoretical question than a practical one.

I have four different App Services in Azure (each one for `dev`, `tst`, `acc` and `prd`), and I want to secure them with SSL.

So, in the portal Azure, I select one of the endpoints *something*-dev.azurewebsites.net and I go to SSL Certificates (I uploaded a certificate there already). Then when I click to add a SSL Binding, a **Hostname** is required.

I can create a hostname by using the Custom Domains option. But this will imply in some costs and extra work. It's not expansive, and the amount of work is not a lot, but what I'm wondering is:

*If I can access already my App Service by using its endpoint (something-dev.azurewebsites.net), why can't I just add SSL binding to this endpoint directly? Why do I need a Custom Domain for it?*

I might be lacking some knowledge about SSL, so I'd really appreciate an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .azurewebsites.net endpoint with SSL directly already (out of the box).  The reason not to do this for production, however, is that that particular domain is not owned by you, it's shared amongst every other web app running on Azure.  So it's usually fine for dev/test environments and proving that your site works on https: ok, but when going to production you should really use your own custom domain - the settings you're referring to are leading you down that path, so you can then import the corresponding certificate.

From the relevant app services [Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/)

> To secure with HTTPS an app that has a custom domain name, you add a certificate for that domain name. By default, Azure secures the *.azurewebsites.net wildcard domain with a single SSL certificate, so your clients can already access your app at https://.azurewebsites.net. But if you want to use a custom domain, like contoso.com, www.contoso.com, and *.contoso.com, the default certificate can't secure that. Furthermore, like all wildcard certificates, the default certificate is not as secure as using a custom domain and a certificate for that custom domain.

Comment: I see. The fact that there's a certificate that points to *.azurewebsites.net also explains why I can access the same endpoints with `https`. But if I want to develop and test endpoints with a proper client certificate validation, I do have to create my own Custom Domains, right?

Comment: Well Azure is giving you "proper client certificate validation" but it's via it's own wildcard, not yours - so your testing is good and valid when using https on *.azurewebsites.net, just don't recommend you use that domain for production.  Azure now gives you DNS management in the portal as well, so you can do that and get a certificate, store it in your vault and assign to your app service all without leaving the portal, and all using your azure credits/bill.

Comment: I was able to add a custom SSL certificate to a default hostname before. It's now not letting me for some reason (the dropdown only contains custom domains now). 

I don't remember how on earth I did it last time, but it was absolutely using the custom certificate with the azurewebsites domain.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't own that domain name! instead, its owned by "azurewebsites.net". The domain your using is simply a sub-domain which you have NO control over. So, if you want an SSL certificate you must lease a domain from a registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need a custom domain to use your own certificate. As I commented above, I had forgotten how to do it. But I've remembered now.

In your web app service settings menu go to Application Settings.

Scroll down to app settings.

In the Key box type "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"

In the Value box type the thumbprint of your custom SSL certificate.

Edit: Don't forget to actually upload the SSL cert.